# How do I know which groups each product is in?

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset, annotate

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=False)   
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
```

Products in group.pk == 1:

```
products = Group.objects.get(pk=1).products.all().values('name')
```

Result:

```
<QuerySet [
    {"name": "product1"},
    {"name": "product2"},
    {"name": "product3"},
]
```

How do I know which groups each product is in? Like this:

```
<QuerySet [
    {"name": "product1", "groups": [{"pk": 1, "name": "group1"}]},
    {"name": "product2", "groups": []"},
    {"name": "product3", "groups": [{"pk": 1, "name": "group1"}, {"pk": 2, "name": "group2"}},
]
```

Thanks!

UPD1.

If we have data:

```
group1 | product 1
group1 | product 2
group2 | product 2
group2 | product 3
```

The idea of creating a table (html) is as follows:

/group/1:

```
product 1 | dropdown (group1)
product 2 | dropdown (group1, group2)
```

/group/2:

```
product 2 | dropdown (group1, group2)
product 3 | dropdown (group2)
```

Comment: Group.objects.get(pk=1).products.all().values() what does this return can you post it?

Comment: Group.objects.get(pk=1).products.all().values() :
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'name': 'group 1'}, {'id': 10, 'name': 'group 10'}]>

Comment: so you are getting group inside the orm, just put group in values and you will get it

Comment: you can try `map(lambda x: {'name': x.name, 'groups': x.group_set.values('pk', 'name')}, Product.objects.all())` but this will return you as list not as queryset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

model.py:

```
context['products'] = Group.objects.get(pk=1).products.all()
return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

template.html:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {{ product.name }}

    COUNT: {{ product.group_set.count }}
    <ul>
        {% for group in product.group_set.all %}
            <li>{{ group.name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

The solution was not difficult, it got confused because of:

```
{% for group in slave_product.group_set.all() %} # ()
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: You never mentioned `template` in your question.

Comment: Yes, I was looking for a solution where the answer would be in the query, but it turned out that this could be done using a template

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding, you want to have reverse lookup from your manytomany field to the Model.

You can get the Product groups like this:

Here `product` is a Product object, and you want to list all the groups associated with that product.

```
product.group_set.all()
```

Comment: I want to see not only the goods to the group, but also to find out in what other groups this product. group1 (product1, product2), group2(product2, proudct3) => for group1(product1[0], product2[1]), and for group2 (product1 [0], product2 [1])

Comment: group2 (product2 [1], product3 [0]) *

Answer (score 0):

values takes another argument called 'group' use that to get the related group. Is not giving the expect result you want. But gives idea.

```
>>> Product.objects.all().values('name', 'group')
<QuerySet [
    {'group': 1, 'name': u'Product 3'}, 
    {'group': 2, 'name': u'Product 3'}, 
    {'group': 1, 'name': u'Product 2'}, 
    {'group': 2, 'name': u'Product 1'}]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have a `Product` instance:

```python
product = Product.objects.get(pk=1)
```

it knows which `Group` instances refer to it. Use the `group_set` field:

```python
groups = product.group_set.all()
```

By declaring a related object (using `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField`), the “other end” of the relationship [gets an implied field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/relations/) to access the instances referring to this one.

In this case, the field is named `group_set` and it is a model manager for `Group` instances that refer to this `Product` instance.